# Router hardware considerations for small business WiFi hotspots

Tags: router, wireless

I'm trying to choose a router for a WiFi hotspot for a small business. What I'm looking to do is run a DD-WRT / OpenWRT system with a simple captive portal. I'm unsure of the hardware requirements for a wireless access point used by more than 4-5 people simultaneously. What are some of the potential bottlenecks or general variables to consider when buying a router for a simple hotspot? Are consumer grade routers sufficient for this sort of load?

Comment: You didn't tell us what sort of load. How many clients are you expecting?

Comment: Probably no more than 30 simultaneous clients

Comment: Questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like DD-WRT/Tomato as much as the next guy, but depending on the environment, you're going to want something a little easier to manage that ties into your router or cloud managed server in the long run. I advise against these types of solutions, though I do understand the occasional need for something lower cost.

That being said, a question about consumer equipment is better placed in the DD-WRT forums than here. Another is Linksysinfo.org, for tomato support. I would recommend [Meraki APs](https://meraki.cisco.com/products/wireless), as they tie into the cloud management portal, have great features, and integrate into all the other equipment they would want very easily. We deploy TONS of these to small businesses, and they just work well. Additionally, you can get your client(/employer) in on Meraki firewalls and switches, eventually making network management of their little LAN extremely easy as well as increasing your visibility of their network. Finally, the Meraki site (And several other business class wireless providers' sites) are very realistic and up front on their datasheets about supported clients, etc.

I forgot to mention, free trials. May as well give it a try. We've never had a client send back the trial equipment, every single site we deploy a trial too ends up loving it.

Comment: Good advice, thank you! But would a general question on hardware requirements for providing a wireless AP really not apply here? I guess that bit was sort of buried in the rest of my question, and I might need to rephrase.

Comment: Also, I've decided to use [Open-Mesh](https://www.open-mesh.com)

Comment: I've heard great things about Open-Mesh, and wanted to give it a try before trying Meraki. I hope it serves you well! As far as what's on topic, look here: [link](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). DD-WRT and Tomato pretty much exclusively go on consumer hardware, which is specifically off topic. This is becoming more the standard even on SF, and support/questions for those firmwares are being pushed into their firmware specific forums. See here as well: [link](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331/serverfault-on-topic-subjects#comment455_333)